# how to use jenkins remotely when it's secure

Tags: xml, security, api, authentication, jenkins

I'm using jenkins api xml to create a new job, see jobs, builds ...
it works only when jenkins is not secure
I'm using this code to create new job

```
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("localhost:8080/createItem?name="+projectName);
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
postMethod.setRequestBody(new FileInputStream(new File("/resources/config.xml")));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
returnCode = client.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass user and api token in your request. [Here's an example](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients).

Comment: it works but only for builds how to configure it with "create a new job"

Comment: Are you sure you the user you are specifying is allowed to create new jobs?

Comment: I couldn't write the code how to attach config.xml file with method Httpost

Comment: One of the examples there (written in Groovy) does exactly that. Maybe you should try replicating it and then examining the HTTP request that it sends. Then find out how to send the exact same request with HTTP API you are using.

Comment: HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=JOBJOB");
post.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("C:/integrationContinue/src/main/resources/config.xml"),"application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"));
HttpGet get1=new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/api/xml"); 
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get1, context);

it's OK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [ruby client](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client) that helps in creating jobs in jenkins through its API. Though Jenkins only allows posting the config XML, this client accepts parameters as a Hash and builds the XML and posts it to Jenkins. You can initialize the client by providing the information about the Jenkins server information and its credentials.

```
gem install jenkins_api_client

require "rubygems"
require "jenkins_api_client"

# Initialize the client by passing in the server information
# and credentials to communicate with the server
client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(
  :server_ip => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "awesomeuser",
  :password => "awesomepassword"
)

# The following block will create 10 jobs in Jenkins
# test_job_0, test_job_1, test_job_2, ...
10.times do |num|
  client.job.create_freestyle(:name => "test_job_#{num}")
end

# The jobs in Jenkins can be listed using
client.job.list_all
```